# Missing GOMP_parallel or GOMP_4.0 in (Docker) jupyter/all-spark-notebook: both R and Python

Tags: python, linux, gcc

I have a question regarding GOMP, that I figured is related to gcc.

I am using this image as a base for some experiments. It seems that I am using an alright version (4.9.2) based on this unmodified image, but I get some strange behaviour with a number of Cython related packages.

Example 1

When running this on the unmodified jupyter/all-spark-notebook docker image, when attempting to run Python I get the following issue,

```
import lightfm

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/lightfm/init.py", line 1, in 
from .lightfm import LightFM

File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/lightfm/lightfm.py", line 7, in 
from .lightfm_fast import (CSRMatrix, FastLightFM,

ImportError: /opt/conda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/lightfm/lightfm_fast.cpython-34m.so:
undefined symbol: GOMP_parallel
```

Things I have tried:

1. Going to the file lightfm.py and moving all of the dependencies onto one line like so:

   `from .lightfm_fast import (CSRMatrix, FastLightFM,
   fit_logistic, predict_lightfm,
   fit_warp, fit_bpr, fit_warp_kos)`

to

```
from .lightfm_fast import (CSRMatrix, FastLightFM, fit_logistic, predict_lightfm, fit_warp, fit_bpr, fit_warp_kos).
```

Same error.

Also tried "`.lightfm`" to "`lightfm`" to change from relative import. Same error.

```
Checking gcc and kernel versions: gcc 4.9.2 Ubuntu 14.04 Linux 00846c176840 3.13.0-67-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 23 13:24:41 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But I think if you just pull the docker image and do a pip install `lightfm` it should replicate the error precisely.

Example 2

When running `pip install xgboost`, the installation succeeds, but when in notebook I attempt to do:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-afdaff4619ce> in <module>()
----> 1 import xgboost

/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost-0.4-py3.5.egg/xgboost/__init__.py in <module>()
      9 import os
     10 
---> 11 from .core import DMatrix, Booster
     12 from .training import train, cv
     13 from . import rabit

/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost-0.4-py3.5.egg/xgboost/core.py in <module>()
     81 
     82 # load the XGBoost library globally
---> 83 _LIB = _load_lib()
     84 
     85 def _check_call(ret):

/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost-0.4-py3.5.egg/xgboost/core.py in _load_lib()
     75     if len(lib_path) == 0:
     76         return None
---> 77     lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
     78     lib.XGBGetLastError.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
     79     return lib

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py in LoadLibrary(self, name)
    423 
    424     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 425         return self._dlltype(name)
    426 
    427 cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    345 
    346         if handle is None:
--> 347             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    348         else:
    349             self._handle = handle

OSError: /opt/conda/bin/../lib/libgomp.so.1: version `GOMP_4.0' not found (required by /home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost-0.4-py3.5.egg/xgboost/libxgboost.so)
```

I have just noticed that this is a recurring pattern and at times can be quite limiting, but I don't understand compilers that well to know if this actually a problem with the image or if that's not really an 'issue', but rather a design decision. Any ideas?

Much appreciated!

Things I have tried:

1. I tried
   `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda gcc` in the terminal
   but to no avail.
2. Also when I tried to do `install.packages('xgboost')` (equivalent) in R, I got this error:

   Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'xgboost', details:
   call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
   error: unable to load shared object '/usr/local/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/R/lib/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so':
   /usr/local/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/R/lib/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so: undefined symbol: GOMP_parallel

`sudo apt-get install libgomp1` also did not help me as it was already installed.

3. Upon suggestion of someone from project Jupyter I 
   ran `conda list` and found this line:
   `libgcc 4.8.5 1 r`

But no gcc I also have glib.
But in terminal:

```
jovyan@aaaaaaa:~/work$ gcc --version      

gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2                                                             
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.                                       
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO              
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
```

**UPDATE**: I now think that the detected compiler is actually an earlier version, so perhaps that is the source of the problem, because upon running

```
%install_ext https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rasbt/watermark/master/watermark.py
%load_ext watermark
# show a watermark for this environment
%watermark -d -m -v -p numpy,matplotlib -g
```

I get the following response:

```
CPython 2.7.11
IPython 4.1.2

numpy 1.10.4
matplotlib 1.5.1

compiler   : GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)
system     : Linux
release    : 4.4.5-15.26.amzn1.x86_64
machine    : x86_64
processor  : 
CPU cores  : 4
interpreter: 64bit
Git hash   :
```

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably author did already find the answer, however I will still leave it here as it may potentially save time for someone.

The issue is indeed related to the wrong version of gcc used. Running this command before installing xgboost on top of `all-spark-notebook` helped me to fix the gomp issue:

```
RUN conda install -y gcc
```

You can see the working solution in my extension of `all-spark-notebook` on [github](https://github.com/omdv/docker-jupyter-xgboost/blob/master/jupyter-spark-xgboost/Dockerfile).