# Loading rpy2 : ImportError: version `GOMP_4.0' not found

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Loading rpy2 on a Jupyter Notebook or in the console brought me the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in         _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in     _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/tests.py", line 23, in <module>
    import rpy2.tests_rpy_classic
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/rpy2/tests_rpy_classic.py", line 3, in <module>
    import rpy2.rpy_classic as rpy
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rpy_classic.py", line 5, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as ri
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
    from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import (baseenv,
ImportError: /home/louis/anaconda3/lib/libgomp.so.1: version `GOMP_4.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
```

- R version : 3.2.3
- Python version : 3.5.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
- OS : ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit
- rpy2 version : 2.8.5

I don't know how relevant it may be, but I have gcc installed, and I can import rpy2 in python.

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.

---

Following omri_saadon's comment, I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to all paths that led to a libgomp directory, which are :

- $HOME/anaconda3/pkgs/gcc-4.8.5-7/lib
- $HOME/anaconda3/pkgs/libgcc-4.8.5-2/lib
- $HOME/anaconda3/pkgs/lib

but each time got the same error :

```
ImportError: path_to_libgomp/libgomp.so.1: version `GOMP_4.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
```

---

So my quest goes on ^^ (I must admit I don't really know the ins and outs of what I am doing).
When I succeed in setting `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` (found in root mode) I have another kind of error :

```
    import rpy2.rinterface as ri                                                                             
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-  packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py", line 92, in <module> 
    from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import (baseenv,                                                        
ImportError: /home/louis/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: PC
```

and when I then try to import first the `readline` package (as it seems to have worked with some) I get :

```
import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
    from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import (baseenv,
ImportError: /usr/lib/libblas.so.3: undefined symbol: gotoblas
```

Comment: please try adding the GCC library (lib or lib64) directory to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH, i.e. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/your-path-to-gcc-6.2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I finally succeeded in installing and using rpy2.

What I did ?

I installed it with the conda package manager, and not pip. With just `conda install rpy2`, I was done.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
RUN conda install -y gcc
```

That seems to work for people with similar issues -- [Missing GOMP_parallel or GOMP_4.0 in (Docker) jupyter/all-spark-notebook: both R and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472058/missing-gomp-parallel-or-gomp-4-0-in-docker-jupyter-all-spark-notebook-both-r#39046588)

Comment: Yeah I did, maybe from another but similar answer ; didn't change anything