# Why can't I load the package Gviz?

Tags: r

I installed the package Gviz successfully, but I can't load it.

```r
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Gviz’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/zyh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/data.table/libs/datatable.so':
  /lib/libgomp.so.1: version `GOMP_4.5' not found (required by /home/zyh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/data.table/libs/datatable.so)
```

Comment: Check if `library(data.table)` works? Also, see related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915479/loading-rpy2-importerror-version-gomp-4-0-not-found How did you install Gviz package?

Answer (score 0):

I hava resolved this question because my \lib\libgomp.so.1 don't have GOMP_4.5.

```sh
    0000000000000000 A GOMP_1.0
    0000000000000000 A GOMP_2.0
    0000000000000000 A GOMP_3.0
    0000000000000000 A GOMP_4.0
    0000000000000000 A GOMP_4.0.1
    0000000000008980 T GOMP_atomic_end
```

then I reinstall libgomp.so.1

```sh
    apt install --reinstall libgomp1
```

then

```sh
    ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 /lib/libgomp.so.1
```

then success.